# Why can't the compiler detect this error regarding Serializable declaration at compile time?

Tags: java, exception, serialization, compiler-construction

From second paragraph of [JavaDoc of Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface :

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
> subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
> of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
> fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
> it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
> class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this
> is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.

Why can't this error be detected at compile time ?

Comment: The compiler enforces the rules in the JLS. That rule is in the Javadoc of a specific class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is designed to check the code based on the requirements of the language, not an individual library. The language could be changed to add a keyword or annotation which perform additional checks and the library could use those in theory.

What would be useful is if the compiler could run library specific checking code in the way it can load annotations (which are currently purely data) This way additional checks could be performed at compile time without it knowing the behaviour of any individual library.

Comment: Can you explain your second paragraph a little more specifically the line "What would be useful is if the compiler could run library specific checking code in the way it can load annotations (which are currently purely data)"

Comment: You can have annotation which refers to class name and contain values. The compiler could use this annotation to run code which is in the library at compile time as the `javac` runs in a JVM and it could call specific routines in any library in a custom class loader.  This would allow the developer of the library to add compile time checks or compile time code injection without significant changes to the language.